# How to create a fixed width circle with css which is center aligned and cut at the edges?

Tags: html, css

How to create a circle like the following: 
[image: this is the image]

which should keep the text inside centrally aligned.

So far what I have tried is:

Created a circle like this and given the left margin as negative and calculating it. But I am failing to keep the circle in cut at the two ends and center aligned. The circle should be of fixed width and while resizing it should get cut equally from left and right.

```
.circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 550px/550px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 550px 550px;
  border-radius: 550px/550px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: calc((100% - 515px)/2);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post [mcve] to get help.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a `div`, which has the height and width of your desired circle. Add the border colour, radius and width. And then use absolute positioning to position it appropriate, whilst using overflow hidden to hide the overflow on the parent.

Comment: If I keep it position absolute then the circle doesn't get cut on left it starts at the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
#circle_container
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0c0c0a;
}
#circle
{
  border: 5px solid #3ecf8e;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}
#circle h2
{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #3ecf8e;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle_container">
    <div id="circle">
       <h2>Some Text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The size of the circle is varying. It should be fixed.

Comment: I thought it is supposed to be responsive?

Comment: Sorry my bad I should remove responsive from my question description.

Comment: If I don't find a solution for a fixed width circle Yours is the best out of all of the solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use some flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.child {
  width: 150%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a responsive circle, you can create it like this:

The html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 20%;
  height:300px;
  background: #000;
}

.circle {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L3mzh8y/)** for you

Basically, with this html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="text">Your text here</div>
</div>
```

I have added a simple `jquery`  function like:

```
var aa = $('.circle').outerHeight();
var bb = $('.container').outerWidth();
$('.circle').css("width", aa).css("left", -((aa / 2) - (bb / 2)));
```

This way you can choose whatever height or width for your `container` and the perfect `circle` will be always positioned right in the middle of the container and cropped both sides as long as the `height` of the container > `width`  which may help you with the responsiveness of your project

```js
var aa = $('.circle').outerHeight();
var bb = $('.container').outerWidth();
$('.circle').css("width", aa).css("left", -((aa / 2) - (bb / 2)));
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.container {
  height:600px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:#000;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.circle {
  border:3px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0px;
  margin:auto;
}
.text {
  background-color:orange;
  height:50%;
  width:80%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="text">Your text here</div>
</div>
```

Change the container size as you wish to check it.

**Edited:** if your example are going to be responsive modules you may check this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vtpc00Lk/1/)** (change the width of the widnow panel)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard technique that allows auto-centering the circle

it is achieved with this properties:

```
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
```

this puts the left of the element in the center of the parent, then moves half of the elemnt to the left

```css
#circle_container
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0c0c0a;
}
#circle
{
  border: 5px solid #3ecf8e;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
#circle h2
{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #3ecf8e;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle_container">
    <div id="circle">
       <h2>Some Text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```